# Using the camera intent to take a picture without an sdcard

Tags: java, android, camera, sd-card

I'm having trouble using the camera when there's no sdcard present.

When there is an sdcard, using the camera is trivial, e.g.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html + a plethora of other examples.

However, I need to make my app available to devices which don't have SD cards, (e.g. the Sony Xperia series.) I've tried modifying the code such that I'm using the internal storage (I think):

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File file = new File(getDir("myDirec", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE), "tmp_photo_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
file.createNewFile();
mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

However, upon result:

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentReturn) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    String path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

...
```

`bitmap` is null.

Which leads me to believe that there's some permissions issue....maybe?

I've tried some of the other internal storage options,  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal e.g. `getFilesDir()` but the same result: null `bitmap`.

Has anyone had any success in using the camera without an sdcard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It works..

```
  private Uri imageUri;

  public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()) {     
      case R.id.btnImageCapture:

    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File dir = context.getDir("directory", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File photo = new File(dir,  "Pic.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_CAMERA);
                    break;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case OPEN_CAMERA:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                 bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                 .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```