# Nullpointer exception while taking picture from camera

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-camera

I am trying to capture a picture from camera (Samsung S3 specific problem) below is my code for the same:

```
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  



    if( requestCode == 1337 && resultCode== RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null){    
                   BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            // options.inSampleSize = 1;
            // options.inPurgeable = true;
            // options.inInputShareable = true;
             thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
             image(thumbnail);
    }else{
                Toast.makeText(CreateProfile.this, "Picture NOt taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
```

The image function:

```
     public void image(Bitmap thumbnail){
       Bitmap photo = thumbnail; 
       ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
       b = bos.toByteArray();
       ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      }
```

Code for starting the camera intent:

```
       if(i==0){
                       Intent cameraIntent = new  Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                       startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST); 
                }
```

The Log Cat:

http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/8388/logcamera.png

http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/7559/camera1u.png

My code is working fine for HTC Wildfire S, Dell XCD35, Samsung Galaxy Grand and Samsung Galaxy Tab, clue less as to why this error is shown in S3. Any leads?

Comment: Post code for starting intent for camera..

Comment: I think `thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");` returns `NULL` Bitmap.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15020131/1278196

Comment: Yes @ user370305 When I comment out that image() statement it works without errors. Line number 1352 is the call to image();

Comment: post logcat as text and not as image!

Comment: Yes as I explained its working for most of the devices albeit S3

Comment: @thepoosh I will keep that in mind, its kind of hard to copy paste the logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well from your `LOGCAT` output it seems like the camera activity is returning a URI to the taken photo. and no thumbnail, just to make sure use:

```
if (extras.keySet().contains("data") ){
       thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
       image(thumbnail);
}
```

Regarding parsing the Uri In the intent you can use the following :

```
Uri imageURI = getIntent().getData();
ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageview.setImageURI(imageURI);
```

so the full code would look something like this :

```
    if (extras.keySet().contains("data") ){
       thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
       image(thumbnail);
} else {
    Uri imageURI = getIntent().getData();
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageview.setImageURI(imageURI);
}
```

Comment: The method getKeys() is undefined for the type Bundle

Comment: It does not solve the issue, as in its not able to satisfy the if condition to true.

Comment: It solves the problem since galaxy S3 doesn't return a "data" extra .
so no crashes anymore instead you should use the uri passed to you in the intent to get a preview manually

Comment: How do I get the URI? Any Insights?

Comment: Man Love Filasteen and love you <3